# Define global variable in _ViewStart.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

We are using `.NET Core 3.1`. We want to define a global variable (current user's email) in `_ViewStart.cshtml` so that all other views can access it. By doing this, we aim to avoid the repetitive code.

The following code:

```cs
@using System.Security.Claims
Your email: @User.FindFirstValue(MyClaimTypes.Email)
```

could be replaced with just this:

```cs
Your email: @email
```

I tried defining email in `_ViewStart.cshtml` like so:

```cs
@{
    Layout = "_MyLayout";
    string email = "test@test.com";
}
```

and later accessing it in `Index.cshtml`:

```cs
Your email: @email
```

But it says that

> The name 'email' does not exist in the current context.

How can we access variable defined in `_ViewStart.cshtml` from all other views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `_ViewImports.cshtml` you can inject the variable like this:

```
@using MyApp.AspNetCore
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{ 
    string UserEmail = "test@test.com";
}
@inject string UserEmail;
```

In the `Index.cshtml` you can reference it by its name:

```
<span>Hello @UserEmail </span>
```

Comment: Thank you. What if we have more than one `_ViewImports.cshtml` file in our solution? Do we have to copy-paste this code into each one of them or is there a way to extract this to one common function somehow?

Comment: Normally you should not have more than one `_ViewImports.cshtml` per app (probably only if you are using Areas). But, you should not get too drastic into "re-usable" code. Having it into multiple `_ViewImports` is still better than having it into each `Index.cshtml`. Also, just like you injected `@inject string UserEmail`, you can inject helper classes which will reduce duplicates

Comment: Yes, we are using areas and each area has its own `_ViewImports.cshtml`. Thank you for the suggestion regarding helper classes.

Comment: @Catalin I've used your code but got an error like: " String.string didn't registered in container" what will I do?

Comment: @Catalin I got error -> No service for type 'System.String' has been registered. Any idea?

Comment: I got the same error, the proposed solution just doesn't work. Better to define a constants class and use that. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74970342/1100255