# Define global variable in _ViewImports.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-6.0, inject

I am using **.NET 6.0**. I want to define a global variable in _ViewImports.cshtml so that all other views can access it.
I encountered the following error
`InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'System.String' has been registered.` 
[SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv6zr.png)

The following code:

`

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    string globalVariable = "text";
}
@inject string globalVariable;
```

`

I made no edits to the program.cs file, which came by default.
By the way, I get similar errors for other types like *int* instead of *string*. I think program.cs also needs editing.
Does anyone know what I should do ?

I tried methods like builder.Services.AddMvc() in program.cs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use Dependency Injection to use global variables. Just declare a static class:

```
namespace SomeNamespace{
    public class GlobalVariables
    {
        public static string globalVariable= "text";
    }
}
```

And then anywhere in cshtml files:

```
@SomeNamespace.GlobalVariables.globalVariable
```

Alternatively, if you insist on using DI, you can define the class with non static declaration, create instance and add it as singleton to DI and then inject it like this:

```
public class GlobalVariablesNonStatic
{
   public string GlobalVariable1{ get; set;}
}
```

Then in program.cs

```
var globalVariablesNonStaticInstance=new GlobalVariablesNonStatic();
globalVariablesNonStaticInstance.GlobalVariable1="Some value";
builder.Services.AddSingleton<GlobalVariablesNonStatic>(globalVariablesNonStaticInstance);
```

and then inject and use like this in cshtml file:

```
@inject GlobalVariablesNonStatic globalVars;
```